# How do I get my loop on pdf_text only to read all the files?

Tags: r

I have a series of 475 files that I need to convert to text. I have written the following code to do that:

```r
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")

for (i in 1:length(files)){
print(i)
files_pdfs <- pdf_text(files[i]) %>% tibble(txt = .) %>% unnest_tokens(word, txt)}
```

It appears to execute successfully but when I inspect the output, it has clearly only read the text from the final file. I tried breaking the corpus of PDFs up into smaller segments and I still get the same problem - always just the text from the final file. I'm sure it's a basic error in my code but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting files_pdfs on every cycle. Try:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")

files_pdfs <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files))
{
  print(i)
  files_pdfs[[files[i]]] <- pdf_text(files[i]) %>% 
                            tibble(txt = .)    %>% 
                            unnest_tokens(word, txt)
}
```